# Prove that $f$ from $\underline{[0,1]}$ to $\underline S^1$ is final.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Problem:**

If we have a map $f: \underline{[0,1]} \rightarrow \underline S^1$, with $f(t) = (cos(2\pi t), sin(2\pi t))$ and $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$.

How can one prove that if $f^{-1}[B]$ is open in $\underline{[0,1]}$ then $B$ is open in $\underline{S^1}$?

---

**Attempt:**

The map $f$ is injective and $f^{-1}[B]$ is open. Let $p \in B$, then there must exist such $\epsilon > 0$ that $f^{-1}[p] = t \in (t-\epsilon, t + \epsilon) \subset f^{-1}[B]$.

Therefore, $f(t) = p \in f[(t-\epsilon, t + \epsilon)] = \{(cos2\pi t', sin2\pi t') \ | \ t' \in (t-\epsilon, t + \epsilon) \} \subset B$.

If I could now show that $B' = \{(cos2\pi t', sin2\pi t') \ | \ t' \in (t-\epsilon, t + \epsilon) \}$ is an open set in $S^1$ it would conclude the proof.

My intuition tells me that I have to somehow find an open set $C$ in $\mathbb R^2$ such that it's intersection with $S^1$ will yield $B'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B=f\bigl(f^{-1}(B)\bigr)$, if $f$ was an open map, then, since $f^{-1}(B)$ is open (due to the continuity of $f$) it would follow that $B$ is open. This will not work, though, since $f$ is *not* an open map (for instance, $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$, but $f\left(\left[0,\frac12\right)\right)$ is not an open set.

However, if a subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ can be written as the union of sets of the form $(a,b)$ (with $a,b\in(0,1)$ and $a<b$) together with sets of the form $[0,a)\cup(b,1]$ (with $0<a<b<1$), then $f(A)$ is an open subset of $S^1$. And, if $B$ is an open subset of $S^1$, then either $(1,0)\notin B$, in which case $f^{-1}(B)$ is an union of sets of the form $(a,b)$ (with $a,b\in(0,1)$ and $a<b$), or $(1,0)\in B$, in which case $f^{-1}(B)$ is an union of sets of the former type together with sets of the form $[0,a)\cup(b,1]$ (with $0<a<b<1$). And then in both cases you have that $f\bigl(f^{-1}(B)\bigr)$ is an open subset of $S^1$.

Comment: "However, if a subset A of [0,1] can be written as the union of sets of the form (a,b) (with a,b∈(0,1) and a<b) together with sets of the form [0,a)∪(b,1] (with 0<a<b<1), then f(A) is an open subset of S1". Could you clarify why that is the case? I don't understand where this comes from wrt. the map definition.

Comment: Note that $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)$ is an arc of the circle $S^1$ (without its extreme points). Such an arc can be obtained as the intersection of $S^1$ with on open disk, and therefore it is an open subset of $S^1$. And if you extend $f$ to $\Bbb R$ (still having $f(t)=\bigl(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t)\bigr)$, then $f\bigl([0,a)\cup(b,1]\bigr)=f\bigl((b,a+1)\bigr)$ (since $f$ is periodic with period $1$, and the same argument shows that $f\bigl((b,a+1)\bigr)$ is an open subset of $S^1$.